# Get user cover picture by Id

Tags: angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I'm working on a web application which is mostly based of Facebook
Graph API. I hold some user's data - actually , the possible
public data available - such as *profile picture*, *name* and *id*. I
wondered how I'll be able to get a direct link to a user cover picture
of a user only by using his id? and I already got the User ID.

This is the code that I used to get the profile picture & it worked-

```
 <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/{{user.id}}/picture?type=large" style="float:left;"/>
```

Now I want to get **cover** picture.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have value for `user.id`  ?

Comment: use ng-src instead of src. if that does not work store the full url in a scope variable and pass that to ng-src.

Comment: suggession by @chandings will work. :)

Comment: @chandings How can I do it? Isnt there a direct link

Comment: $scope.profilePicURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+user.id+"/picture?type=large"; 
<img ng-src="{{profilePicURL }}" style="float:left;"/> 
This should work.

Comment: @chandings Yes. I got the  Profile picture. Now I want to get the cover image.

Comment: sorry i misunderstood your issue. I cannot help you here as I have no knowledge of facebook api.

Answer (score 1):

To get the cover picture of a user, make this call-

```
\GET http://graph.facebook.com/{user-id}?fields=cover
```

You'll get the image url in `source` key of the JSON response:

```
{
  cover: {
    id: "111222333",
    offset_y: 55,
    source: "https://scontent-a.xx.fbcdn.net/.....jpg"  // that's the cover photo url
  },
  id: "111222"
}
```